# OData, Web Api 2 and deeply nested objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I've been trying to find the answer to this and haven't had any luck. Assume I have a model that looks something like this:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public ICollection<B> Bs {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public ICollection<C> Cs {get;set;}
}

public class C
{
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string Something {get;set;}
}
```

Can I write a Web Api 2 OData controller while can be queried like so: 
    /odata/A(1)/B(2)/C(3)/Something

If this is redundant please point me to the place I should look. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions for the part of **Custom Routing Conventions**. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

*(This is an old Post but it missing a crucial response to this standard question for developers who are new to OData)*

> If this is redundant please point me to the place I should look

Yes URL routing like that is redundant when the `Id` property on Class `C` is unique.
The resource that you are operating on is an instance of `C` so the default v4 *way* to execute a `Something` action on the `C` resource is to call the `C` resource directly:

`~/odata/C(3)/Something`

This would not require any custom `ODataRouteAttribute` at all if you define the `Something` action on the `CController`. The keys for `A` and `B` should be redundant and discoverable from the `C` object. This is different to many other `Repo` based API patterns but important to support standard routes and conventions that we get OOTB.

Whilst you *could* write your own URL route to match your expected pattern, the parenthesis is special convention in the OData v4 routing conventions to indicate the key of the specific item to operate on or the URL parameters to pass through to a function call.

> Keep in mind that by deliberately implementing a custom route you will make it hard for standards compliant clients to interact with your service, in most cases the driving motivation to adopt OData is to provide a standards compliant API.

If you really wanted a URL like that, then I would suggest dropping the `()`:

`[ODataRoute("A/({key})/B/{bKey}/C/{cKey}")]`

Then you can define this as a bound Action on the `A` controller that also has `bKey` and `cKey` parameters in addition to the standard `key` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One way to add a conventional rule to support deep navigation as Qian described as above. In OData V4 you should be able to use attribute routing to support your URL. add a Route annotation to your controller like below:

[ODataRoute("/A({key})/B({key})/C({key})")]

please be noted the official webapi V4 support will come in June.